# Advice for starting a new job?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, job-change, behavior

What things should i keep in mind while joining a new job.How do i make a long lasting impressions on colleagues and boss?

Thanks

Comment: Then ask specific questions that can be answered in the format of this site.

Comment: Sorry, this question is really out of scope. Generic advice includes: be social, professional, hard working, punctual, and maybe bring some snacks for your colleagues on a couple of Friday mornings. Helpful? Maybe. But not exactly what you asked, is it?

Comment: Keep in mind that long lasting impressions aren't always a good thing as if you arrived to work naked you would be memorable but not in a good way.

Comment: don't break wind during the interview either

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be listen more than you talk. Ask pertinent questions but respect that your colleagues have other things to do than answer your questions, so don't be a pest. And most especially don't criticize their systems until you have produced some work of your own and gained a reputation from knowing your stuff.

Think about what kind of person you want to be viewed as and act accordingly.